# C# Headless browsing through proxy

Tags: c#, html, parsing, proxy

I need to add a action to my program, which makes the following, using headless action, i.e. without starting browser or something like this:

- Connects to remote web server through a proxy server that uses currently logged user authentication (Active Directory).
- Loads a page from that server and selects an item from a drop-down list, as the page has a lot of js coda that populates data based on the selected item.
- Parses the populated data to extract the needed information.

I am totally lost in the net, as there are many ways to achieve some of the goals, but not all in the same time.

**EDIT**:

The page source for that select looks like this (guess it is a .net page):

```
<div class="rddlSlide" id="ctl00_MainContent_DropDownGameMode_DropDown" style="display:none;">
        <div class="rddlPopup rddlPopup_Black">
            <ul class="rddlList">
                <li class="rddlItem">Team League</li><li class="rddlItem  rddlItemSelected">Hero League</li><li class="rddlItem">Quick Match</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div><input id="ctl00_MainContent_DropDownGameMode_ClientState" name="ctl00_MainContent_DropDownGameMode_ClientState" type="hidden" />
</div>
```

Comment: Selenium and few other alike.

Comment: How did they fail?

Comment: The site I am trying to access is a .Net based one, with elements I can't really click/select from. Or at least I am failing.  
    
Check this one:
http://www.hotslogs.com/Player/HeroOverview?PlayerID=2761845  

I want to select some of the 3 drop downs, but they are a PostBack non-standard components.

Comment: Try to ask another question describing that problem specifically and how you find it to be failing. From what I understand about Selenium it should work find, but I am far from even being a knowable novice user of it. But that question should get a lot more views/replies than this question.